# spring boot batch: why it didn't use my postresql database

Tags: spring

I configured the application property as

```
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/example
spring.datasource.driverClassNname=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=oracle
logging.level.org.springframework=LOG
```

And from the debug log I could see it successfully read the postregresql datasource setting. But the app still use JobRepositoryFactoryBean from HSQL. What else I need to add?

```
2014-12-14 20:44:23.524  INFO 13989 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: HSQL
```

In the build.gradle I have

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:1.2.0.RELEASE"
    compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1102-jdbc41'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo in your configuration:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassNname=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Should be:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

(i.e. `driverClassName` instead of `driverClassNname`)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IDE like Spring STS, I suggest you try building the jar file on the command line and running the jar independent of the IDE

I had a problem where STS launched the spring boot app and started using the test setup!! I to was getting HSQL datasource and not the configured Oracle datasource

mvn package
java -jar target/??.jar

helped identify the real problem for me